# Flutter Datepicker - close on select date, not by OK confirm button?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Is it possible for a flutter datepicker to close as soon as a date is pressed? something like a jquery datepicker ...

```
  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101)
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        selectedDateF = "${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0];
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want `showDatePicker` without re-implementing it from `CalendarDatePicker`,
then you can get a copy of source code, patch it, and use it:

- `bin/patch`

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  set -eu

  VERSION=$(flutter --version | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

  curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/flutter/$VERSION/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart \
    | perl -0777 -pe "s/import 'package:flutter\/widgets.dart'.+'theme.dart';/import 'package:flutter\/material.dart';\n\/\/ ignore_for_file: unnecessary_null_comparison/s" \
    | perl -pe "s/onDateChanged: _handleDateChanged,/onDateChanged: (date) {_handleDateChanged(date); _handleOk();},/" \
    | perl -pe "s/\.textScaleFactor;/.textScaleFactor; \/\/ ignore: deprecated_member_use/" \
    > lib/patched/date_picker.dart
  ```
- `lib/main.dart`

  ```dart
  import "package:flutter/material.dart" hide showDatePicker;
  import "package:your/patched/date_picker.dart" show showDatePicker;
  ```

This patched `showDatePicker` saves a user from an extra click.

Tested for Flutter versions 3.7.6 - 3.16.3.
If a newer version becomes incompatible, you can easily update the patching script and re-run it.

Comment: I wanted to create a PR for Flutter to enable this feature with `quickPick: true`, but found a similar PR already done and closed as not in line with guidelines, etc - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/102750#issuecomment-1145624190

Comment: best answer and kudos for bringing up this method to replace parts of material.dart with alternate versions

Comment: thanks @woens, I've added a line required for current Flutter 3.16.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CalendarDatePicker` widget. Here's a complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Date Picker',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Custom Date Picker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(
              _selectedDate.toString().split(' ').first,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final result = (await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<DateTime>(builder: (context) => DatePicker(initialDate: _selectedDate)),
                ))!;
                setState(() {
                  _selectedDate = result;
                });
              },
              child: const Text("Pick Date"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DatePicker extends StatelessWidget {
  final DateTime initialDate;

  const DatePicker({required this.initialDate, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Pick Date"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop<DateTime>(context, initialDate),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue[50],
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: CalendarDatePicker(
            initialDate: initialDate,
            firstDate: DateTime(2021),
            lastDate: DateTime(2025),
            onDateChanged: (DateTime selectedDate) {
              Navigator.pop<DateTime>(context, selectedDate);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```